# ImportError: cannot import name 'asn1' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location)

Tags: python, python-3.x

While importing paramiko there are some dependency modules which get imported, when the import happens it fails with below error. Can someone help please.

```
    File "python_program_to_fetch_the_latest_file_and_mail_it_as_a_attachment_v2.py", line 6, in <module>
        import paramiko
      File "/home/tclshare/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
        from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
      File "/home/tclshare/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 91, in <module>
        from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
      File "/home/tclshare/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 25, in <module>
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
      File "/home/tclshare/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.base import (
      File "/home/tclshare/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py", line 9, in <module>
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.types import (
      File "/home/tclshare/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/types.py", line 7, in <module>
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import (
      File "/home/tclshare/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py", line 10, in <module>
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import (
      File "/home/tclshare/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py", line 6, in <module>
        from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import asn1
    ImportError: cannot import name 'asn1' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Please reformat this properly using markdown

Comment: its done now... and thanks for the advice....

Comment: you are missing output: ImportError: cannot import name 'asn1' from

Comment: from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import asn1
ImportError: cannot import name 'asn1' from ----- 'asn1' is already present in the specified directory but still it not picking up the location.

Comment: the pyi file 'asn1' is present inside ----/**/**/tools/bin/python/python3.7.6-sles/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/asn1.pyi

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, when I try pysftp on lambda function. for my local it's working fine.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this really needs a better documented solution to avoid any further headaches and pain, Cryptography is a Core dependency to many other important modules.

## Problem and Available solutions:

Cryptography depends on some external system dependencies and external binary files that need to be properly installed on system. When this module is packaged or copied to another system, but not properly installed from scratch, you can run into issues due to missing dependencies or version incompatibility.

Best way to fix bindings errors is by properly installing cryptography onto the system, with proper system compatible dependencies and links. You have 2 options:

1- Upgrading and installing directly on the system through pip with `pip install cryptography` or the consumer module that installed this module for you. This is the official way to install cryptography. This will install all necessary system dependencies and their links, and make them available . You can connect and install with pip through ssh connection for virtual machines. Also for AWS EC2 or EMR clusters you can use `bootstrap actions` which will install these dependencies when creating the virutal machine.

2- Building a custom cryptography module bundle from source: This is in case you do not have access to 'pip install' and need to build a custom image with dependencies and links that match and are specifically compatible with your runtime (e.g. like in AWS Lambda functions). [Link to cryptography build instructions](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-macos).

This is probably why it cannot load  the `asn1.pyi` file (the ‘.pyi’ is a python-interface file, to load what looks like a rust binary).

[Github issue explaining this same error due to dependencies Installation error](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/8433).

*Note: If you packaged the module manually to a AWS runtime without system tools and binaries needed this is probably the problem. You need to guarantee that all the external system dependencies are compatible and properly installed/updated for cryptography operation.*

#### Modules that can have this issues:

This proper installation is very important for some cryptography dependant libraries like; snowfalke-connector-python; paramiko ;  Django ; OpenSSL ; pyOpenSSL ; PyCryptodome.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing this issue when I lowered down lambda python version to 3.8 it started working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35009232)